# Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: грамматика

"Почему-то в предыдущих несколько тысяч сообщениях это правило не рассматривалось". Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, правильнее так:

"Почему-то в предыдущих нескольких тысячах сообщений это правило не рассматривалось".